# Растяжение изображения по оси OY на Qt

Tags: qt

По заданию необходимо растянуть(либо сжать) изображение по оси OY на заданный коэффициент. Попытался написать, как итог, загружается первоначальное изображение. Подскажите, как можно исправить программу, чтобы она работала корректно.

mainwindoww.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QRect>
 
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Work();
}
 
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::Work()
{
    sc = new QGraphicsScene;
    QPixmap qp(ui->graphicsView->size());
    QPainter pn(&qp);
    pn.fillRect(QRect(0,0,ui->graphicsView->width(),ui->graphicsView->height()), QBrush(Qt::white));
    QString url = "D:/Desktop/sc.jpg";
    QPixmap px(url);
    pn.drawPixmap(0,0,ui->graphicsView->width(),ui->graphicsView->height(),px);
    sc->addPixmap(qp);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(sc);
}
 
void MainWindow::Change()
{
    QString sk;
    QPixmap qp(ui->graphicsView->size());
    QPainter pn(&qp);
    sk = ui->lineEdit->text();
    k = sk.toInt();
    int wd;
    wd = ui->graphicsView->width();
    wd *= k;
    QRect r;
    r.setWidth(wd);
    r.setHeight(ui->graphicsView->height());
    QString url = "D:/Desktop/sc.jpg";
    QPixmap px(url);
    pn.drawPixmap(r,px);
    sc->addPixmap(qp);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(sc);
 
}
```

mainwindow.ui:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QMainWindow>
 
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
 
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
 
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QGraphicsScene *sc;
    QPixmap px;
    QPixmap qp;
    QPainter pn();
    int k;
    void Work();
    void Change();
 
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
 
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: А зачем QT? Просто запустите convert из ImageMagic.

Comment: По заданию нужно делать на Qt. Была бы моя воля, сделал бы всё давно иначе и не парился так сильно

Comment: `QPixmap QPixmap::scaled(int width, int height, Qt::AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode = Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::TransformationMode transformMode = Qt::FastTransformation) const`.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled-1